# Join lines in R plot based in order in data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use ggplot, preferably geom_line, to plot data points joined by a line where the data points are joined in the order they appear in the data frame. Essentially what excel gives for a joined scatter plot.

MWE

```
library(ggplot2)

# Sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  time = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
  x = c(0, 1, 2, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 0),
  y = c(0, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1.2, 1, 0.9)
)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
geom_line()
```

This is ordering the points by x-value and joining. I need to join by time (the df is sorted by time). My actual data frame is about 1500 rows and the x-values go up and down quite a bit (multiple loops in the data).

I tried the above and three minor variations suggested by chatGPT, which all gave the same basic result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `geom_path()`, not `geom_line()`. That's what it does.

The first sentences of the shared `?geom_line`/`?geom_path` help page is:

> `geom_path()` connects the observations in the order in which they appear in the data. `geom_line()` connects them in order of the variable on the x axis.

Generally, I'd suggest consulting the help pages, at least briefly, before turning to ChatGPT.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_path()
```

[image]